# How to combine two bitmaps into one so that their relative position should not be changed in rotating the combined one?

Tags: android, bitmap, merge, image-rotation

In my application,I want to combine two bitmaps for example a leaf and its shadow, in water.I am able to combine those bitmaps and make the combined bitmap freely fall from the top of the screen with some rotation in a live wallpaper.In my combined image the shadow is a little bit below  the original leaf and left to it.If the combined image is rotating with some angle,the shadow also rotates with that angle.It seems to be like that the shadow is rotating like original image. But the shadow position should be always below  the original image. But some times shadow is appearing on top of the original image while the combined image is falling with rotation because they are merged.I do not want this.I want the shadow always below the original image under any instance.How can i achieve this?Please help me.I am providing my code to combine the two bitmaps.

```
 public static Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
    Bitmap bmoverlay = null;
 bmoverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmoverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, null, new Rect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth() ,    canvas.getHeight()), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 20, 20, null);
 return bmoverlay;
     }
```

Please suggest me how to do or any other method which does my requirement?Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is that Bitmap used for?

Comment: it is used for freely falling from the top of the screen to bottom with some rotation

Comment: ok,  in other words: how do you use it?

Comment: I am rotating the combined image with matrix.postRotate(angle).

Comment: do you use it like Canvas.drawBitmap for example?

Comment: canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint);

Comment: so draw it two times: a shadow then a leaf? make sure to translate a Matrix for a second call

Comment: one more thing is there.When i touch the original image,the original image is moved away from the touched position.In the similar manner,the shadow also should move away like it is attached to the original image.i.e they must be like a group and  the shadow should appear always at the bottom of the original image in rotating it.

Comment: it should be like a leaf floating on the water.when leaf is rotated on the water with some movement,its shadow is also rotated with the same rotation  without changing its relative position with respect to the leaf

Comment: as i said: draw it twice

Comment: Superb yaar.It has worked.you have great logic.thanks a lot.

Comment: @pskink - i am drawing two bitmaps on a canvas but then the second bitmap doesnot seem to draw at the correct positions, and  on using `canvas.setRotate` the overlay is displayed at the back. could u please help ?